# Set height to 100% of browser viewport when container is bigger than viewport?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm working on a website and I need to set a div's height and width to cover the entire area of the browser viewport like many modern websites. However, I can't simply set its height to 100% because its parent element is another div whose height **must** be set to bigger than the browser window. Is there another way of doing this?

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/8raws5ee/) a code sample set up similar to my website.

HTML

```
<div class="entireThing">
  <div class="contentBox">
  </div>
  <div class="contentBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.entireThing {
    height: 8000px;
    width: 100%;
}
.contentBox {
    height: 100%; /*This works only if parent is same size as window*/
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the ‘vw’, ‘vh’, ‘vmin’, ‘vmax’ units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

Use viewport-percentage lengths. In this case, `100vh`.

```
.contentBox {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqzxf3sg/)

---

You can also use `calc()` to subtract the `10px` top/bottom margins:

```
.contentBox {
    height: calc(100vh - 20px); /* Subtract the 10px top/bottom margins */
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gj28z8ww/)

..it's just worth pointing out that you need to establish [a new block formatting context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214768/strange-margin-issue-with-a-display-inline-block-child/27790007#27790007) on the parent element in order to [prevent the collapsing margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214768/strange-margin-issue-with-a-display-inline-block-child/27790007#27790007).

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I've never heard of this before. Thank you!

Comment: Note: you need the space around the `-`, but how do you know how much to subtract? I tried `html, head, body, { margin: 0px;}`, but it still is over sized.