# Margin not transparent

Tags: html, css

I have a `header`. Inside I have another `<div>` with a repeating background image. I want 60px of margin on the top and bottom to reveal a solid background color set in `<header>`, however, it's not showing the background color `#2f2f2f` it's white. What am I missing?

HTML

```
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Stuff here</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
```

CSS

```
header{
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.header{
    background: #2f2f2f url("../images/tweed.png") repeat left top;
    margin: 60px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are observing [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> [**8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

One solution would be to set an `overflow` other than `visible` on the parent element. In this case:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ky4ufxak/)

```
header {
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Take a look at [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214768/strange-margin-issue-with-a-display-inline-block-child/27790007#27790007) of mine for a longer explanation with more workarounds.